# Is there a Future class in JDK which is interruptable and can register a callback straightforwardly?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a function which makes a RPC call. (In this function I'd like to set up a thread and try to call remote service infinitely until it succeeds). I want the caller can be notified when it succeeds, also, it should stop trying when the caller decides to cancel the call.

what class should I return in this function?

If return a CompletableFuture, I can register a callback by `future.thenRun()`, but `future.cancel(true)` won't interrupt the working thread.
If return a Future/FutureTask, there isn't a straightforward method to register a callback.

To make it concret, I'm looking for something like this:

```java
interface Service {
  SomeFutureClass<T> request();
}
```

The client code may like:

```java
SomeFutureClass<T> future = request();

// I can either register a callback
future.thenRun(() -> {
  // someLogic
});

// or tell the service to stop trying
future.cancel(true);
```

If there isn't such a class, what is the best way to implement function like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `Executor` and wrap your call.
*task* is your `RPC-Call`, *listener* is your Notification.
With `cancel()` you can cancel the call, otherwise it reschedules itself until a result occurs.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class RPCCaller
{
    ExecutorService service=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public <V> RepeatedCaller<V> callRepeatedly(Supplier<V> task, Consumer<V> listener) {
        return new RepeatedCaller<V>(task, listener);
    }

    public class RepeatedCaller<V> implements Runnable, Supplier<V> {
        private final Supplier<V> task;
        private boolean cancel;
        private V result;
        private Consumer<V> listener;

        public RepeatedCaller(Supplier<V> task, Consumer<V> listener) {
            this.task = task;
            this.listener = listener;
            service.execute(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                result=task.get();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
            if(result!=null)
                listener.accept(result);
            else if(!cancel)
                service.execute(this);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            this.cancel = true;
        }

        public V get() {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```